# Strong finite induction

Tags: logic, induction, natural-numbers

If I have a proposition $P(n), n \in \{ 1,2,\ldots, m\}$ and I want to prove it by induction, can I proceed like this:

1. Show that $P(1)$ is true
2. Suppose that $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \{1,2,\ldots,t\}$, where $t \in \mathbb{N}^*, t \le m-1$ and show that $P(t+1)$ is true.

This is something like complete induction on $\mathbb{N}$. It works? Thanks!

Comment: Of course.  And actually if make the statement $Q(n):= $ Either $P(n)$ is true or $n > m$ then that'd be a regular old natural induction.